# Three.js skybox works when small but is black when big

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created a skybox using the code below. When the skybox cube is 1,000 x 1,000 x 1,000 it shows up perfectly. However, when I expand it to 10,000 x 10,000 x 10,000 it just shows up as black. Do I need to change a setting in order to support a larger skybox?

```
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x000044);
scene.add(ambientLight);

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xff8040);
directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight);

// Add skybox
var directions  = ["miramar3.jpg", // right of me
"miramar1.jpg", // left of me
"miramar4.jpg", // above me
"miramar5.jpg", // beneath me
"miramar6.jpg", // behind me
"miramar2.jpg", // in front of me
];
var skyGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1000, 1000, 1000 );    

var materialArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    materialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( directions[i] ),
        side: THREE.BackSide
    }));
var skyMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materialArray );
var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyGeometry, skyMaterial );
skyBox.position.y += 200;
scene.add( skyBox );
```

Comment: What is your cameras far plane set to? This could be a clipping issue, please add to the code how you are creating your camera.

Comment: You're right, that fixed it! Go ahead and repost your comment as an answer and I'll mark it accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem related to camera clipping. Clipping means everything behind the cameras far-plane is not rendered (= shows up as black in your scene).

The [perspective camera](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/PerspectiveCamera) in the three.js docs uses a near-plane value of `1` and a far-plane value of `1000`:

`var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 1, 1000 );`

So if you created your camera like this and use a skybox with the size of `10.000` every side of the cube is too far away (= is behind the far-plane) and gets clipped.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new scene calling it say

```
var skyScene = new THREE.Scene();
```

you could put your box in it, and render that before your main content.

you would set up

```
renderer.autoClear = false,
```

and your render loop would have something like

```
renderer.clear();
renderer.render( scene , camera );
renderer.render( skyScene , camera );
```

might need a bit more logic but this is the general idea. This way you don't have to manage the background with the rest of the geometry. One way of not writing depth is to stick a

```
depthWrite: false
```

in the parameters you pass to the material

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My skybox still turns black at an edge length much over 1,000. I'll play around with it some more. (Maybe my computer is just too lame to render anything bigger than that?)